# React, Flexbox: I want my div to transitionally rise from the bottom of a flex container

Tags: css, reactjs, dynamic, flexbox, transition

Here is the css for my wrapper container in which the div in question resides:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper{
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center bottom; 
    background-color: gray;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Now the following div I want to remain fixed to the bottom of the scroll-less SPA, but upon the change of a class (from infoTabHidden to infoTabDeployed), I want it to go from invisible to dynamically rise from the bottom of the window and cover most of the screen.

```
.infoTabHidden > * {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0%;
}
.infoTabDeployed{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    bottom: 0%;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Rather than rising right now, the div sort of just phases into existence... 
Any tips? Thanks everyone for your valuable time!

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. The `> *` in infoTabHidden was still affecting the class after it had been changed.... however that works.